# Setting an image for a UIButton in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uibutton

How do you set the image for a UIButton in code?

I have this:

```
UIButton *btnTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
btnTwo.frame = CGRectMake(40, 140, 240, 30);
[btnTwo setTitle:@"vc2:v1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(goToOne) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btnTwo];
```

but don't see what will set the image for it.

Answer (score 430, accepted):

Objective-C

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btnTwo setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Swift 5.1

```
let btnImage = UIImage(named: "image")
btnTwo.setImage(btnImage , for: .normal)
```

Comment: As a sidenote: this will show the image, but the button title text will be hidden.

Comment: This is code is fully working but i'm getting image with parsing so how can i done this as
this code is worked for me in UIImage case:-
largePick.image = aNewsInfo.smallImageData;

how can i done this with UIButton...
Can you help me...

Comment: @slcott, where does [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) state that?  I don't see it suggest anywhere that `setImage` is deprecated.  (It appears to me you are confusing `UIButton.setImage` with `UITableViewCell.image`, which *is* a property deprecated as you stated.)

Comment: Attention: If you use anything else than UIButtonTypeCustom, the image will be blue in iOS7 and 8.

Comment: For Swift 3: btnTwo.setImage(btnImage, for: UIControlState.normal)

Comment: or even simpler, the second line in Swift

`btnTwo.setImage(btnImage, for: .normal)`

Answer (score 58):

Mike's solution will just show the image, but any title set on the button will not be visible, because you can either set the title or the image.

If you want to set both (your image and title) use the following code:

```
btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btnTwo setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnTwo setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: what is the difference between **setImage** and **setBackgroundImage** ?

Comment: setBackgroundImage will stretch the image over the width of the button over your title text while setImage will make the button an image ignoring title text without stretching the image.

Answer (score 22):

Before this would work for me I had to resize the button frame explicitly based on the image frame size.

```
UIImage *listImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list_icon.png"];
UIButton *listButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

// get the image size and apply it to the button frame
CGRect listButtonFrame = listButton.frame;
listButtonFrame.size = listImage.size;
listButton.frame = listButtonFrame;

[listButton setImage:listImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[listButton addTarget:self.navigationController.parentViewController 
               action:@selector(revealToggle:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *jobsButton = 
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:listButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = jobsButton;
```

Comment: @jrasmusson just wanted to add that the 3 lines of fiddling with the frame can also be written in `[listButton sizeToFit]`

Answer (score 12):

In case of Swift User

```
// case of normal image
let image1 = UIImage(named: "your_image_file_name_without_extension")!
button1.setImage(image1, forState: UIControlState.Normal) 

// in case you don't want image to change when "clicked", you can leave code below
// case of when button is clicked
let image2 = UIImage(named: "image_clicked")!
button1.setImage(image2, forState: UIControlState.Highlight)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this

```
[btnTwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 10):

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44);
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonimage.png"] 
               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self 
     action:@selector(btnSendComment_pressed:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Answer (score 9):

You can put the image in either of the way:

```
UIButton *btnTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
btnTwo.frame = CGRectMake(40, 140, 240, 30);
[btnTwo setTitle:@"vc2:v1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnTwo addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(goToOne) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[btnTwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//OR setting as background image

[btnTwo setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name.png"] 
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:btnTwo];
```

Comment: This part of the code has got me confused.

<code>
btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
</code>

What is btnImage?  That wasn't in the original code.  Is that a new button?

Comment: you can directly set the image of the button instead of taking another image object like this:  [btnTwo  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

Comment: you have to have buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect to UIButtonTypeCustom other wise button will not display as per as your image.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution to add an `UIImage` to my `UIButton`. The problem was just it displays the image bigger than needed. Just helped me with this:

```
_imageViewBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectImageView];
_imageViewBackground.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientBackgroundPlain"];
[self addSubview:_imageViewBackground];
[self insertSubview:_imageViewBackground belowSubview:self.label];
_imageViewBackground.hidden = YES;
```

Every time I want to display my `UIImageView` I just set the var `hidden` to `YES` or `NO`. 
There might be other solutions but I got confused so many times with this stuff and this solved it and I didn't need to deal with internal stuff `UIButton` is doing in background.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry so much framing the button from code, you can do that on the storyboard. This worked for me, one line...more simple.

```
[self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"yourPic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-Locked.png"]])
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-Unlocked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements....
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-Locked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3 version** (butt_img must be an Image Set into **Assets.xcassets** or **Images.xcassets** folder in Xcode):

```
btnTwo.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "butt_img"), for: .normal)
btnTwo.setTitle("My title", for: .normal)
```

Anyway, if you want the image to be scaled to fill the button's size, you may add a `UIImageView` over it and assign it your image:

```
let img = UIImageView()
img.frame = btnTwo.frame
img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
img.clipsToBounds = true
img.image = UIImage(named: "butt_img")
btnTwo.addSubview(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

For swift 5+

```
let image = UIImage(named: "icons-multiply")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
btn.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```