# Setting a background image for UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am a newbie with Objective C.  How would I set the background of this button to an image (image is already in the resources folder in XCode, "blue_button.png") instead of clearColor? Also, I would prefer that I use the image as the shape of the button rather than the UIButtonTypeRoundedRect.

```
btnClear = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];

btnClear.frame = CGRectMake(115, 350, 90, 40);

[btnClear setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

btnClear.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[btnClear addTarget:self action:@selector(clearAction:) 

forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:btnClear];
```

I know how to do this in Interface Builder but I would rather learn about doing it in XCode.

Comment: you can do that in Interface Builder if you use nib

Comment: you should accept an answer, it's good for all involved...

Answer (score 44):

This works:

```
UIButton *btnClear = [[UIButton alloc] init];
btnClear = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
btnClear.frame = CGRectMake(115, 200, 90, 40);
[btnClear setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnClear setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnClear addTarget:self action:@selector(clearAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btnClear];
```

Answer (score 8):

See the [UIButton class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html): `-setBackgroundImage:forState:`

Create your button with type `UIButtonTypeCustom` instead of `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` if you don't want to use the rounded corner style.

Answer (score 6):

You need to declare your button with the following UIButtonTypeCustom type:

```
btnClear = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
```

Then you should be able to use the follow:

```
[btnClear setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

There are 6 different control states that can be set.

```
enum {
   UIControlStateNormal               = 0,
   UIControlStateHighlighted          = 1 << 0,
   UIControlStateDisabled             = 1 << 1,
   UIControlStateSelected             = 1 << 2,
   UIControlStateApplication          = 0x00FF0000,
   UIControlStateReserved             = 0xFF000000
};
```

Here are some references that may help:

[UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

[UIControl Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState)

Comment: This does work but I am now unsure how to set the title.  I was using <code>[btnClear setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];</code>

Comment: have a look at this and see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469474/setting-an-image-for-a-uibutton-in-code

Comment: You can either set and image or a tile but there are some things you can do to get the title to show

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` to set background color to image. To use image you should change button style to custom.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4+

```
var btnClear = UIButton()
btnClear = UIButton(type: .custom)
btnClear.frame = CGRect(x: 115, y: 200, width: 90, height: 40)
btnClear.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "blue_button.png"), for: .normal)
view.addSubview(btnClear)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to set button to `UIButtonTypeCustom` `- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` method also works for `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set button background with images on the Internet, using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is an elegant choice:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIButton+WebCache.h>

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[button setBackgroundImageWithURL:imageURL forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```