# How to set NSButton background image

Tags: cocoa

How can I set a background image to NSButton ?

`[_myButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]];`

This will only change the image icon in the button, but there s no option to setbackgroundimage as `UIButton`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting a background image for UIButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608454/setting-a-background-image-for-uibutton)

Comment: @emreoktem - NSButton is not UIButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was what I was after : http://osdir.com/ml/cocoa-dev/2010-06/msg00539.html

> Set the image (by name). Set the 'Position' to icon only, no text
>   (second  option from left in array of position buttons), and uncheck
>   'bordered'.

Answer (score 4):

```
[_myButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]];
[_myButton setBordered:NO];
[_myButton sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:-

```
NSString* img = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Your Image" ofType:@"png"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:img ];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];
[yourButton setImage: image] ;
```