# UIImageView places on UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I want to place an `UIImageView` on `UIButton` programmatically (with constraints). The `UIButton` is implemented from `Storyboard`. I don´t find example from the net. I tried this code:

```
//Test Image button
UIImageView* iqImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iq1"]];
iqImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.iqCategoryButton.frame.size.width, self.iqCategoryButton.frame.size.height);
iqImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
[self.iqCategoryButton addSubview:iqImageView];
```

The problem is at this moment, the frame´s size of the button is not equal as it will be seen on the screen (due to constraints).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608454/setting-a-background-image-for-uibutton just set a background image on your button

Comment: That was not the question. I want to place my UIImageView inside the UIButton with help of constraints

Comment: You can use PureLayout and pin your imageView to the button like left->left, top->top etc.