# How to put an image on a UIButton / Where can I find good icons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, icons

In my application I have many `UIButton` and I would like to put an image instead of the simple `UIButton`that Xcode propose to us.

Like something on http://icones.pro/?s=refresh , cause I want to reload some data.

I don't really know how to process, I found some answers but isn't it like Eclipse with Android where we need to add the image in some drawables folders?

And if someone know some other good websites where I can find a lot of icons I would be thankfull :)

Comment: you should have just search it on google before posting question here. its very basic thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting an image for a UIButton in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469474/setting-an-image-for-a-uibutton-in-code)

Comment: You can also put image and text at same time in a UIButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write below code in `viewDidLoad` :

```
[YourButtonOutlet setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can also set UIButton image from attributes inspector:
[image]

You can find some awesome icons  from here:

https://www.iconfinder.com/

https://design.google.com/icons/

Comment: That looks great but... Where do I need to put the file of the image that I want? In which folder of my project? Thanks

Comment: You have to put (drag & drop ) required images in "Images.xcassets" project folder.

Comment: Oh ok everywhere and it's working thanks a lot :D