# Unable to set imagesize for UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I've gotten as far as setting the image (if it is available) but for some reason I cannot set the size of the image to the imageview (if it has an image or at least a cutout preview) I tried something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469474/setting-an-image-for-a-uibutton-in-code?rq=1)

But as you can see, the image ends up taking up the whole cell not sure why...[image]

Here's what the layout should look like... I tried to go for a aspect fill... but the end result comes to about the same...

[image]

Edit: added code, I forgot to add... that would help a lot right?

Setting the tabeview cells

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{
    var cell:commentTableViewCell
    if commentList[indexPath.row].cellType == 1{
        //drink
        cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "drink",for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
        cell.drinkName.text = commentList[indexPath.row].commentOwner
        cell.drinkPrice.text = commentList[indexPath.row].comment

        return cell
    }
    else{
        //comment
        cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "comment",for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
        cell.ownerTitle.text = commentList[indexPath.row].commentOwner
        cell.commentContent.text = commentList[indexPath.row].comment
        if commentList[indexPath.row].isFile{
            //cell.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            cell.imageView!.image = commentList[indexPath.row].imageFile
        }
        else if !commentList[indexPath.row].isFile {
            cell.imageView!.image = nil
            cell.imageView!.removeFromSuperview()

        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

The parsequery:

```
    func getLocalComments(point:PFGeoPoint){
    var temp = [CommentDetails]()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let qComments = PFQuery(className: "UserCommentary")
        let qDrinks = PFQuery(className: "venueDrinks")
        if self.type == "House Parties"{
            //Query the bars
            qDrinks.whereKey("venueName", equalTo: self.id)
            qDrinks.whereKey("venueID", equalTo: self.venueName)
            qDrinks.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

            qComments.whereKey("venueID", equalTo: self.id)
            qComments.whereKey("venueName", equalTo: self.venueName)

            do{

                let qReply1 = try qDrinks.findObjects()
                if qReply1.count>0{
                    let comment:CommentDetails = CommentDetails.init(comm: "Test", ven: self.venueName, venId: self.id, owner: PFUser.current()!.username!, vote: 0)
                    var i = 0
                    while i < 2 {
                        let item = qReply1[i]
                        print(item)
                        comment.cellType = 2
                        i+=1
                    }
                    //temp.append(comment)
                }
                let qReply2 = try qComments.findObjects()
                for item in qReply2{
                    let comment:CommentDetails = CommentDetails.init(comm: "Test", ven: self.venueName, venId: self.id, owner: PFUser.current()!.username!, vote: 0)
                    comment.commentOwner = item.object(forKey: "owner") as! String
                    comment.comment = item.object(forKey: "comment") as! String
                    comment.isFile = item.object(forKey: "image") as! Bool

                    if comment.isFile {
                        let dataPhoto:PFFile = item.object(forKey: "imgFile") as! PFFile
                        let imageData:NSData = try dataPhoto.getData()
                        let image:UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData as Data)!
                        comment.imageFile = image
                        comment.cellType = 2
                    }
                    temp.append(comment)
                }
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(temp)
            self.commentList.removeAll()
            self.commentList = temp
            self.commentTableView.reloadData()

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to do here:

- Set the image view's `clipsToBounds` to `true`. Otherwise, no matter how small the image view is, it will show the part of the image that lies *outside* it.
- Give the image view sufficient constraints to determine its width and height. Otherwise, it will try to be the size of the image.

Comment: I want the image to to an aspect fit, so it fills the image but doesn't display the image in full.

Comment: Aspect fit displays the image in full ("fit").

Comment: Oh, so is there a way to make the image fit into the imageview? Sorry some of this seems a bit confusing. Would I have to resize the image each time so it meets the criteria of the imageview?

Comment: Is there a way to resize the image so that it fits inside the imageview?

Comment: Did you even read my answer?? I've explained what to do. Try doing it!

Comment: Thanks for the assist, but still no luck. I spent the day trying to fit the image.. Yes I did set the clip bounds to true... But I can't seem to force it to fit within the give constraints.