# Change image when a button is clicked using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am trying to switch between two different images when clicking on a button. Below is the code I wrote so far. However, this will only display one image and not toggle between them.

```
-(IBAction)show {

    BOOL img = true;

    if (img = true) {
    UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UnCheck.png"];
    [imageview setImage:img1];
        }
    else {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Check.png"];
        [imageview setImage:img];
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting an image for a UIButton in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469474/setting-an-image-for-a-uibutton-in-code) Just change the state to your required state.

Comment: If you set a true Bool inside the first line of the method it runs always the code into the if.

Comment: @kerberos The problem I've got is that the code always run else if the if statement is set to "false"

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your code:

First, `img` is a local variable inside your tap handler, so each time that function runs, it will be set to `true`.

Second, your `if` statement actually contains an assignment (`=`) instead of a comparison (`==`), so even if `img` wasn't already `true` it would be when you execute the `if` statement.

All of this means that your image is always going to be `UnCheck.png`.

You need to use a property, outside the function, so that the state is tracked properly. `img` is also a pretty poor variable name, `checked` or `isChecked` is probably better.

Then your button handler method simply needs to toggle this property and set the appropriate image.

```
@property BOOL isChecked;

-(IBAction)show {
    self.isChecked = !self.isChecked;

    NSString *imageName = self.isChecked ? @"Check.png":@"UnCheck.png";
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [imageview setImage:img];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Helped me a lot

Comment: You can refactor it a little more by using image isHighlighted property too.

Add following code where `imageview` initialized.
`UIImageView(image: UIImage?, highlightedImage: UIImage?)`

And use below in your `(IBAction)show`
imageview.isHighlighted = self.isChecked